# Decomposition of a cumulative density function into a discrete and a continous part.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Decomposition of a cumulative density function into a discrete and a continous part.

Has anyone some reference to this?

I cannot find a proof to this.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have no reference, but on the page of wikipedia about cdf : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function, there is a plot of a cdf that has both a discrete and a continuous part.

I'm not sure what you're looking for, but I would say that such a cdf would be valid
$$F(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}0 &\text{ if } x<0 \\ 
0.5 &\text{ if } x=0 \\
0.5 + x &\text{ if } 0< x < 0.5 \\
1 & \text{ if }0.5 \leq x \end{array}\right.$$

and the pdf would be $$f(x) = 0.5\delta_{0}(x) + \mathbf{1}_{[0;0.5]}(x) $$

Comment: Thank you. This is a good example but this can be shown in general as far as I understood the literature. But I could not find any proof of this statement